# I am getting error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I get the correct result using the postman for a post request with the same params and headers. I get an error when I try to use the request module in python. You may see my postman screenshot for more info.
I see a json response in Postman which I try to get the same result from my code.
here is my code.

```
        headers = {'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8' , 
                        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa-AF;q=0.8,fa;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6'}
        payload = {"oppId":329656}
        r = requests.post('https://www.grants.gov/grantsws/rest/opportunity/details', params=payload , headers=headers )
        response = r.json()
        print(response)
```

the error I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requestDemo.py", line 120, in <module>
    response = r.json()
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "E:\anaconda\envs\AHG_web\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

if you wish to check the URL, here is the website, click on the first row of the table and check the network tab of the [enter link description here](https://www.grants.gov/web/grants/search-grants.html)   dev tool.

[image]
I want to recieve the correct json response.

Comment: before `response = r.json()` print the status_code - what do you get?

Comment: print(r.status_code) gives me 415 , why I get 415?

Comment: if I see the body in my post man it is written the same as Id=329656 without any curly braces ,

Comment: this explains why you dont get the json. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415 - you may need to change the content type header.

Comment: try `params=json.dumps(payload)`

Comment: thank you I got it, I changed the content type in the header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' and it works now

Comment: does it work now?